# /execute doesn't work for my custom command

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I made a custom /spawn command that teleports the sender to spawn
I tried to use it doing "/execute as Mouton_redstone run spawn", "Mouton_redstone" being my minecrfat username.
But it tells me that my command doesn't exist, when I run it myself, it works fine ("Zbim !" message)

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ3D2.png)

plugin.yml :

```
name: MyEasySpawn
version: '${project.version}'
main: fr.mouton_redstone.myeasyspawn.MyEasySpawn
api-version: 1.18
authors: [ Mouton_redstone ]
description: Adds a /spawn command and more

commands:
  spawn:
    description: Teleports you to spawn
    usage: /<command>
```

Comment: Can you show your code ? Can you run it yourself ?

Comment: I can run the command myself, there is a lot of code behind because I started to add a lot of things to adjust the command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't run custom commands with the /execute command.
Someone had the same problem a couple of years ago [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/341943/).
You can try to implement your own execute command or use other workarounds.